# Regex expression for extracting numbers followed by 'KGS'

Tags: regex

I would like to identify and extract numeric values followed by 'KGS' (no space between number and 'KGS'. The strings might contain other numbers NOT followed by 'KGS' that should be ignored. Example:

```
This is a 123 sample (500KGS) string.
```

`500` should be extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a less strict pattern here since you are not validating, but extracting values. Right now, your regex will only extract `56`, `578.56` or `52,456` like values, and values like `2,400.56` won't get matched.

Use

```
/\d[\d.,]*(?=\s*KGS)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7InDO/2). Or, with capturing:

```
/(\d[\d.,]*)\s*KGS/i
```

The result is in Group 1. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7InDO/3).

The `\d[\d.,]*` will match a digit, and then zero or more digits, `.` or `,`.

The `/i` modifier will make the regex case-insensitive. Depending on the regex flavor, you may even use an inline version of this modifier, `(?i)` - just put it at the pattern start.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:
(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s?(KGS)

Comment: Thank you Pan Wiktor. Is there an easy way to make the match for 'KGS' case insensitive?

Comment: Absolutely, `/\d[\d.,]*(?=\s*KGS)/i` or `(?i)\d[\d.,]*(?=\s*KGS)`